# Why the caption text is not visible in carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Screen shot of bootstrap example from https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/#myCarousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD82l.jpg)

I am trying to use similar code for my website but can't seem to figure out what's going on here. It's happening on their website as well. When I try to view it on a small screen, the caption text inside carousel disappears.

Comment: Provide the fiddle.

Comment: It says in the example [from the docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#with-captions) "We hide them initially with `.d-none` and bring them back on medium-sized devices with `.d-md-block`". Just remove these classes. If you still have problems post the code.

Answer (score 0):

It disppaers due to CSS media query rule, which hides caption on certain breakpoint.

I've check Bootstrap's webpage and the code looks like this:

```
<div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
    <h3>First slide label</h3>
    <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .d-md-block {
     display: block!important;
  }
}

.d-none {
     display: none!important;
}
```

Comment: That helped. Thank you.  @KiranPurbey